# installing a second mythtv front-end

Tags: mythtv

I have just completed the installation of mythTV inn Ubuntu 18.04. It works.  Now I need to make files Sneed on the backend master available to a satellite machine.  The documentation appears to indicate that one simply need to install the myth front-end on the satellite and link it to the matter backend.  I did that (or at least I tried), but it didn't work.  The setup found the workstation containing the master backend; the passwords in the xml files on the satellite are the same as on the matter backend.  The satellite can ping the matter backend workstation.  The failure message indicates that the new front-end can't access the database.  The default user on the satellite is a member of both the mythic and mysql groups.  Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Allowing mythfrontend on a remote machine to access mythbackend running on a second machine.**

If mythfrontend is not being run on the same machine as mythbackend, there is some additional configuration required to allow remote access to mythbackend.

Two separate issues related to MYSQL on the mythbackend host may be at work:

**First**, ensure that networking is enabled in the my.cnf file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' on the mythbackend host machine. In this file, by default there exists either the following (depending on version) which prevents a remote mythfrontend from accessing the info on the database on the mythbackend host.

```
skip-networking
```

or

```
bind-address localhost
```

or

```
bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.

So a suggested solution is to change 'bind-address' to the machine's LAN IP address - although this will only work if the IP address is static and not dynamically assigned.

Note

If bind-address is used, it can only be configured to use 1 IP address.

```
#skip-networking
```

or

```
#bind-address localhost
```

or

```
#bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

or

```
bind-address 192.168.3.4
```

Note

No '#' on the final example

**Second**, it may be necessary to alter the privileges table for the MythTV database to allow the frontend to access the mythbackend (NB; The mythfrontend communicates with the mythbackend by logging on to its mysql database -- generally as the user mythtv. On some systems by default mysql will not allow a user on another machine to login. The following grants users with id mythtv from any machine access to the mythtv databases).

This can be done by executing the following from the command line on the mythbackend machine (thanks to Torfinn Ingolfsen, Norway for this).

**Notes**:

The 'passwd' in the command below should be the password listed in MythTV's configuration, which is also found in ~/.mythtv/mysql.txt

By default, the mysql database root user has no password, so this also should be changed by securing the default mysql accounts, refer to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html

```
mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql> grant all on mythconverg.* to 'mythtv'@'%' identified by 'passwd';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> exit;
```

You may also have to open port 3306/tcp in your firewall.